# Site Statistics: What exactly does views/day mean?

Tags: support

Pardon this question from a non-techie. Does "views per day" indicate total views or views per user?  For example, if I check in 5 times during a day is that considered 5 views or just 1 since the views are from a unique user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a count of [unique visitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_visitor) per question, summed. For example, if 100 users each view 10 questions each that is 1,000 views.

Comment: correct, is is closest to unique visitors. But caveat: it is by IP address, by question. It'd really best be expressed as "unique visitors on each question, summed". If I visit 5 different questions, that would increment the counter on all 5 questions. We think this is a pretty good metric though